# Rails google drive gem issue with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, google-drive-api, rubygems

I have accessed my google sheet file using google drive gem with command

```
 GoogleDrive.saved_session("./config.json")
```

Config file contains credentials to connect to drive. On my local machine server asks to paste as url in browser and paste authentication key.

I have done all this and on my localhost code is working fine.

But I have deployed my code to heroku and I am facing the issue. App crashes with logs saying to to find authentication code from given url and paste it.

I find this authentication code successfully but on heroku how to paste it? On localhost I was able to put in the key in terminal. How to make it run on heroku.

Please help me.

Comment: check this https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/issues/172

Comment: I am not much clear from this link. I implement code like this

session = GoogleDrive.saved_session("./config.json") 
ws     = session.spreadsheet_by_title(current_user.sheet_name).worksheets[0]

all the client id and secrets are in config.json. What change I need to make to make it work?